# How do I prevent my cucumber puppeteer tests from running twice

Tags: node.js, cucumber, puppeteer

My project is cucumber puppeter in node.js.

I have 2 feature files and 2 step files.

login.feature, login.steps.js

rollForward.feature, rollForward.steps.js

---

In the rollForward.feature file I have **'Given I have logged in'**

In the **login.steps.js** file, I have a step Given("**I have logged in",...**

My tests are running twice. How do I run only once

### **login.feature code**

Feature: Login

```
    # to check first cucumber works or not
    Scenario: Verify login
            Given The browser is open
            When I open pro2 site
            When I enter valid username and password
            When I click the login button
            Then I see Select Company Dialog

            When I click Select dropdown
            Then I see list of companies

            When I select IndoreC company
            When I click Login to Company
            Then I go to home page
```

### **login.steps.js
some non relevant code deleted**

```
const { When, Then, Given } = require("cucumber")
var chai = require('chai')
    , expect = chai.expect()
    , should = chai.should()
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config({ path: 'config.env' });

const company = 'xxxx';

async function openBrowser() {
    return await this.launchBrowser();
    // this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null })
    // this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
}

async function openPro2Site() {
    expectedUrl = 'https://pro2.xxxxxxxsx.com';
    return await this.visit(expectedUrl);
}




async function selectCompanyDialog() {
    await this.page.waitForFunction(
        'document.querySelector("body").innerText.includes("Select Company")'
    );
}

async function loginToCompany() {
    await this.page.waitFor(500);
    await this.page.click('button[class="btn btn-block mt-3"]');
}


Given("I have logged in", { timeout: 60000 }, async function () {
    await openBrowser.call(this);
    await openPro2Site.call(this);
    await enterValidUsernameAndPassword.call(this);
    await clickLoginButton.call(this);
    await selectCompanyDialog.call(this);
    await clickSelectDropdown.call(this);
    await selectIndoreCCompany.call(this);
    await loginToCompany.call(this);
})

When('I select xxxx company', selectxxxxxCompany);

Given("The browser is open", { timeout: 30000 }, openBrowser)
When("I open pro2 site", { timeout: 10000 }, openPro2Site);

When("I enter valid username and password", enterValidUsernameAndPassword);

When("I click the login button", clickLoginButton);

Then("I see Select Company Dialog", selectCompanyDialog);

When("I click Select dropdown", { timeout: 10000 }, clickSelectDropdown);

Then("I see list of companies", async function () {
    await this.page.waitForFunction(
        'document.querySelector("body").innerText.includes("IndoreC")'
    );
});

When('I click Login to Company', loginToCompany);

Then('I go to home page', async function () {
    await this.page.waitFor(1500);
    await this.page.url().should.equal('https://pro2.xxxxxx.com/#/');
    console.log('got to login 99 tweice');
});
```

**and here is the rollForward.feature file
-------------------------------------------**
Feature: Roll Forward

```
Scenario: Verify pro2 login, roll forward
    Given I have logged in


    When I select mymodel in model list
    When I click on the Revenue folder in left nav
    When I click on Revenue Summary 2 in left nav
    When I go to Revenue Summary page
    When I click on Roll Forward in top menu bar
    When I see Roll Model Forward Dialog

    When I click on arrow to the right of the current Month
    When I see a confirmation dialog

    When I click Save
    #When I see a completion toaster within 4 minutes
    Then I confirm that Forecast start period in the grid has increased by 1 month
    When I save the Forecast date
    When I click on TOC
    Then I confirm TOC Forecast start period is correct

    When I again click on Roll Forward in top menu bar
    Then I confirm that the Forecast start period in the dialog box has increased by 1 month
```

Edit 1: When the second test runs it runs in a 2nd browser window. It occurred to me to delete the login.feature file. When I did that the second test did still run but in the original browser window.

Edit 2:
I combined features into 1 feature file with only 1 scenario. I also combined all steps into 1 step file. In the last step I close the browser. Yet the test still runs twice!!! What is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing your build process copies the feature files and you configured your test to search for features in a common parent directory of both the build and source directory.

Comment: I didn't know what you meant by "build process", but I looked at my script definition that I use to start the test in my package.json file and sure enough I had a duplication of the last term. Problem solved. This was really 'bugging' me and I am very greatful for your suggestion.